# Adjuncting with a "day job"?

Tags: united-states, job-search

Let's say I want to be a college professor, but the field I am interested in is known for having an unbelievably bad job market (worse than usual). We're talking people coming out of top 5 programs not being able to find jobs at liberal arts colleges. To add, let's say I would prefer to be working in a very specific region (e.g. northeast), which narrows my options further.

Is it feasible, after my PhD, to try to get adjunct work in my desired region, while also having a "day job" in something totally different? In other words, working a <= 40 hr/wk job to pay the bills, but teaching two classes or so at night at a college nearby? While publishing independently on any remaining free time, maybe?

Or do the demands of adjuncting make this setup basically impossible? Is it difficult to find adjunct work even in a major city?

Comment: Might you, instead, Post something about your field that others could grasp, rather than having an unbelievably bad job market (worse than usual) or people coming out of top 5 programs not being able to find jobs at liberal arts colleges

Answer (score 34):

First, adjuncts get paid almost nothing unless they have exceptional skills in some narrow field.  Skills far beyond those of the typical recent PhD graduate. Those who try to live on adjunct pay have an impossible schedule and are unlikely to have health, etc., benefits.

However, some people I know, have made a success at it because the money means little to them and they already have a very secure research position in industry. They teach a course per term "just for fun", rather than for any significant boost in income.

That can be a viable lifestyle, but you have to love your day-job for it to make sense, and it needs to give you the freedom to spend several hours a week on your hobby - teaching. The latter isn't a problem for many unless they are in some pressure cooker environment.

These folks don't interact heavily with other faculty, however, since their work day doesn't give the freedom for that - not face to face anyway. They publish, but more as a result of their full time research position than their adjunct position. They are probably limited to undergraduate teaching, which can be challenging, and are unlikely to have supervision over theses, and such, though it may be possible in a few rare cases.

Find a stable position of some sort and then ask around for teaching opportunities. But, I suggest, that you draw your main income and also satisfaction from that day job.

Comment: This is a really good answer.

Comment: In the California CC at which I work (in the largest higher ed system in the country), adjuncts with a PhD and no experience are paid a bit over $2000 per credit hour taught, precisely 87.5% of one thirtieth of the annual salary of an equally experienced full-time faculty member. One gets health insurance by teaching one course each semester for two semesters, and one is enrolled in the same retirement plan as the full-timers. While of course most parts of the country are not as advanced as California, I always think these claims that all adjuncts are working for pennies need tempering.

Comment: @KevinArlin, I'm guessing that you have union protections.

Comment: Why, yes, naturally. California is a civilized place, after all! The OP mentioned the northeast so I took a look and the salary situation at CUNY, the next biggest community college system in the country, looks comparable. Certainly nobody should ever take an adjunct job in a red state unless they have volunteer-type motivations like those you described.

Comment: Cuny isn't a community college, it's more equivalent to cal state. Community colleges are pretty good usually - the nyc suburb private colleges are around 1k/credit with no chance you're getting insurance.

Comment: Also cuny and the nys community colleges are still mostly full time faculty - it's the smaller private colleges that are leading the adjunctification drive

Comment: And about ten (3 credit) courses per year, possibly at different institutions, possibly all different, still leaves you below the median wage for the US. And CUNY has graduate programs, actually.

Comment: CUNY has 7 community colleges as part of its organization. I'm a permanent lecturer at one of them. As of early last year, adjuncts comprise 56% of faculty throughout CUNY. Adjuncts here get not-great pay, but health and retirement benefits. Some get a 3-year appointment contract. However, right this second we're going through massive adjunct layoffs due to state and city funding cuts and enrollment declines in the pandemic. This is a major fighting point for our union (e.g., public protest and many meetings in last week).

Answer (score 0):

The modern STEM adjunct professor is probably not the job that you're expecting it to be.

Most schools that actively hire adjuncts do so because they've successfully commodified academic education. You'll be given a course to teach and a course package from a major publisher (which includes a textbook, a code for the online component, lecture slides, and a tool for creating self-grading homework assignments and for building tests). You'll be expected to deliver this unit of education to students.

Any students that are performing poorly will be managed by academic advisors from another unit - you'll be required to open support tickets so that the advisement team can try to keep them on track to graduate. This is necessary because the incredible turnover of academic faculty means there's basically no longer term relationship between teachers and students.

There are exceptions - jobs at larger universities teaching specialty stuff for medical or engineering schools. Unless you're actively recruited for this you will not get these jobs.

If you're still interested it won't be hard to find a position - just send your CV to the local schools and they'll probably get back to you the next time they're hiring for fall. Many of these schools will also have evening classes for working students, which is also good for the working professor.

Comment: This is basically accurate though it’s a bit much of you read it as implying the adjunct will be expected to follow the publisher lecture slides.

Comment: Give it a couple years and [I think it'll be the actual lectures, not slides](https://mobile.twitter.com/AaronLinguini/status/1352009211501289472).

Comment: -1 I would want citations/references to support the radical claims here. It doesn't match my experience at all. I'm very skeptical that "no longer term relationship between teachers and students" is broadly accurate.

Comment: @Libor I think that disability accommodations for students that have problems with remote learning would hopefully prevent the complete automation of university teaching.

Comment: Radical claims? This is what WileyPlus and McGraw-Hill Connect are marketed **for**. You might adjunct somewhere the full time faculty still have enough power to push back, but one good budget crisis and this is gonna start looking uncomfortably likely to be your future too.

Comment: Also, related to the actual question - someplace churning adjuncts (like Manhattan, or Mercy, or Berkeley or etc) is gonna have dozens of openings and CUNY is gonna have a handful that aren't reappointments. If you're looking for an adjunct job today, you're more likely to end up someplace you're delivering units of McGraw-Hill education.